# Can´t use a list with more than one decimal place as input in python

Tags: python, windows, list, python-idle

I created an algorithm that organizes a list using sequential search and I am having a problem. I'm using Idle on Windows to program in python (version 3.4.2 ) and this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iohvl.png

As you can see(I hope) i tried to create an input with numbers with more than one decimal place, and it worked in this strange way. My question is: how can i fix it?

Here is the code:

```
#coding:utf8
import time
x=list(input("Type a list:"))
start=time.time()
lista=[]
for a in range(len(x)):
    for b in range(len(x)-1):
    for c in range(b+1,b+2):
        if x[b]>x[c]:
            lista.append(x[b])
            lista.append(x[c])
            x[b]=lista[1]
            x[c]=lista[0]
            lista=[]
        print (x)
        end=time.time()
        print ((end-start)*1000,"ms")
```

If you cant see the image:

```
Input:['1','23','45','67','89','43','51','23','34']
```

---

```
Output:["'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", "'", ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '[', ']']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> x=list(input("Type a list:"))
> ```

does nothing that helps you. You need to parse the string.

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Actually, I used x=eval(input("Type a list:")). I tried to use     ast.literal_eval(x), but it didn't work. Your answer helped me a lot, thank you man.